# What need to set Build Process Parameter Metadata Value Format String

Tags: batch-file, tfs, build-process, tfsbuild

I have added a Argument of type

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.ServerFileBrowserEditor, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls
```

in build definition of TFS.
[image]

What should i need to put under Value Format String textbox.

Whenever i am running build definition i am getting below error.

```
 F215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \GlobalMarkets.GlobalMarketsWorkflowApprovalSystem\Markets Workflow Auto build: Cannot set unknown member 
'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.ProcessParameterMetadata.ValueFormatString'.
```

1. How can i fix this error.
2. I actually wanted to execute a bat file with my custom process steps. So how can i pass argument to my bat file (Like label, buildnumber etc)

Thanks